# Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 92 : {myTest=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION}

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have created a sample application to check my producer's code. My application runs fine when I'm sending data without a partitioning key. But, on specifying a key for data partitioning I'm getting the error:

```
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 37 : {myTest=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION}
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 38 : {myTest=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION}
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 39 : {myTest=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION}
```

for both consumer and producer. I have searched a lot on the internet, they have suggested to verify kafka.acl settings. I'm using **kafka on HDInsight** and I have no idea how to verify it and solve this issue.

My cluster has following configuration:

1. Head Node: 2
2. Worker Node:4
3. Zookeeper: 3

MY producer code:

```
public static void produce(String brokers, String topicName) throws IOException{

    // Set properties used to configure the producer
    Properties properties = new Properties();
      // Set the brokers (bootstrap servers)
    properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", brokers);
    properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
  properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());

    // specify the protocol for Domain Joined clusters

    //To create an Idempotent Producer
    properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, "true");
    properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
    properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, Integer.toString(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.TRANSACTIONAL_ID_CONFIG, "test-transactional-id"); 
    KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(properties);
    producer.initTransactions();
    // So we can generate random sentences
    Random random = new Random();
    String[] sentences = new String[] {
            "the cow jumped over the moon",
            "an apple a day keeps the doctor away",
            "four score and seven years ago",
            "snow white and the seven dwarfs",
            "i am at two with nature",
         };


    for(String sentence: sentences){
        // Send the sentence to the test topic
        try
        {
            String key=sentence.substring(0,2);
            producer.beginTransaction();
            producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topicName,key,sentence)).get();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          System.out.print(ex.getMessage());
            throw new IOException(ex.toString());
        }
        producer.commitTransaction();
    }
}
```

Also, My topic consists of 3 partitions with replication factor=3

Answer (score 4):

I made the replication factor less than the number of partitions and it worked for me. It sounds odd to me but yes, it started working after it.

Comment: Partitions? You mean brokers?

Answer (score 3):

The error clearly states that the topic (or partition) you are producing to does not exist.

Ultimately, you will need to describe the topic (via CLI `kafka-topics --describe --topic <topicName>` or other means) to verify if this is true

> Kafka on HDInsight and I have no idea how to verify it and solve this issue.

ACLs are only setup if you installed the cluster with them, but I believe you can still list ACLs via `zookeper-shell` or SSHing into one of Hadoop masters.

Comment: I have made sure that my topic exists, also the code runs perfectly fine when I send without a partition key. Why does it show error on adding a partition key?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "partition key". It would be the "record key", and even if you don't actually set one, then it is still sent as `null`. What partitioner are you using?

Comment: For the sake of completeness, the same happens when the topic is not created also.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same issue while creating a new topic. And when I described the topic, I could see that leaders were not assigned to the topic partitions.

Topic: xxxxxxxxx Partition: 0    Leader: none       Replicas: 3,2,1 Isr:
Topic: xxxxxxxxx Partition: 1    Leader: none       Replicas: 1,3,2 Isr:

After some googling, figured out that this could happen when we some issue with controller broker, so restarted the controller broker.

And Everything worked as expected...!

Answer (score 0):

If the topic exists but you're still seeing this error, it could mean that the supplied list of brokers is incorrect. Check the `bootstrap.servers` value, it should be pointing to the right Kafka cluster where the topic resides.

I saw the same issue and I have multiple Kafka clusters and the topic clearly exists. However, my list of brokers was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when topic is not present or partition is not present. In my case my `amazon msk` cluster configuration having `auto.topic.cretion.enable` as `false`. Customizing the configurations and setting it as a `true` resolved the issue.

Comment: You shouldn't change that. Just create a new topic